# Lauch parameters / flags / command line options / switches in Perl

Tags: perl, parameters, switch-statement, command-line-arguments, flags

As you see, I'm not completely sure what they're actually called.. I'm talking about when I launch a file, for instance `client.pl`. I would normally launch this by typing `perl client.pl` in terminal.

What I want to do, is to be able to call `perl client.pl -e`, and that this would set a specific boolean to true. Like, "if `-e` was used to lauch this file, `$b = true;`". Else, it would be false.

I've read something about the `#!/usr/bin/perl` line that usually is on the top, but I can't seem to understand if that is even related to what I'm trying to do..

Comment: You might be looking for something like [Getop::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3A%3ALong), but you can also just do `my $b = shift` for a simple version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line arguments are stored in the `@ARGV` array. If you just want to test if the first argument equals `'-e'`, you can do this:

```
$b = $ARGV[0] eq '-e';
```

Otherwise, take a look at getopt, see e.g. here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=88222.

Comment: You can also use `$b = grep { $_ eq '-e' } @ARGV` for a bit more flexibility.